# Running same Docker image with different flags on AWS and saving results

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an experiment I'd like to run 100 different times, each with a command line flag set to a different integer value. Each experiment will output the result to a text file. Experiments take about 2 hours each and are independent of each other.

I currently have a Docker image that can run the experiment when provided the command line flag.

I am curious if there is a way to write a script that can launch 100 AWS instances (one for each possible flag value), run the Docker image, and then output the result to a shared text file somewhere. Is this possible? I am very inexperienced with AWS so I'm not sure if this is the proper tool or what steps would be required (besides building the Docker image).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/) with the [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) plugin to spin up the instances and the [Docker Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html) to `pull` your images / `run` your containers or the [Ansible Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html). For example:

```
.
├── playbook.yml
└── Vagrantfile
```

The `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  N = 100
  (1..N).each do |server_id|
    config.vm.box = "dummy"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.define "server#{server_id}" do |server|
      server.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
        aws.access_key_id = ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
        aws.secret_access_key = ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
        aws.instance_type = "t2.micro"
        aws.block_device_mapping = [
          {
            "DeviceName" => "/dev/sda1",
            "Ebs.VolumeSize" => 30
          }
        ]
        aws.tags = {
          "Name" => "node#{server_id}.example.com",
          "Environment" => "stage"
        }
        aws.subnet_id = "subnet-d65893b0"
        aws.security_groups = [
          "sg-deadbeef"
        ]
        aws.region = "eu-west-1"
        aws.region_config "eu-west-1" do |region|
          region.ami = "ami-0635ad49b5839867c"
          region.keypair_name = "ubuntu"
        end
        aws.monitoring = true
        aws.associate_public_ip = false
        aws.ssh_host_attribute = :private_ip_address
        override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
        override.ssh.private_key_path = ENV["HOME"] + "/.ssh/id_rsa"
        override.ssh.forward_agent = true
      end
      if server_id == N
        server.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
          ansible.limit = "all"
          ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
          ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
          ansible.raw_ssh_args = "-o ForwardAgent=yes"
          ansible.extra_vars = {
            "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Note**: this example does [ansible parallel execution](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html#ansible-parallel-execution) from the [Tips & Tricks](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html#tips-and-tricks).

The [`ansible`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) `playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
  - name: get instance facts
    local_action:
      module: ec2_instance_facts
      filters:
        private-dns-name: '{{ ansible_fqdn }}'
        "tag:Environment": stage
    register: _ec2_instance_facts

  - name: add route53 entry
    local_action:
      module: route53
      state: present
      private_zone: yes
      zone: 'example.com'
      record: '{{ _ec2_instance_facts.instances[0].tags["Name"] }}'
      type: A
      ttl: 7200
      value: '{{ _ec2_instance_facts.instances[0].private_ip_address }}'
      wait: yes
      overwrite: yes

  tasks:
  - name: install build requirements
    apt:
      name: ['python3-pip', 'python3-socks', 'git']
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    become: true

  - name: apt install docker requirements
    apt:
      name: ['apt-transport-https', 'ca-certificates', 'curl', 'gnupg-agent', 'software-properties-common']
      state: present
    become: true

  - name: add docker apt key
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
      state: present
    become: true

  - name: add docker apt repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable'
      state: present
    become: true

  - name: apt install docker-ce
    apt:
      name: ['docker-ce', 'docker-ce-cli', 'containerd.io']
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
    become: true

  - name: get docker-compose
    get_url:
      url: 'https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-{{ ansible_system }}-{{ ansible_userspace_architecture }}'
      dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
      mode: '0755'
    become: true

  - name: pip install docker and boto3
    pip:
      name: ['boto3', 'docker', 'docker-compose']
      executable: pip3

  - name: create docker config directory
    file:
      path: /etc/docker
      state: directory
    become: true

  - name: copy docker daemon.json
    copy:
      content: |
        {
            "group": "docker",
            "log-driver": "journald",
            "live-restore": true,
            "experimental": true,
            "insecure-registries" : [],
            "features": { "buildkit": true }
        }
      dest: /etc/docker/daemon.json
    become: true

  - name: enable docker service
    service:
      name: docker
      enabled: yes
    become: true

  - name: add ubuntu user to docker group
    user:
      name: ubuntu
      groups: docker
      append: yes
    become: true

  - name: restart docker daemon
    systemd:
      state: restarted
      daemon_reload: yes
      name: docker
      no_block: yes
    become: true

  # pull your images then run your containers
```

Answer (score 0):

The only approach that I can think of is using AWS SSM to run multiple commands but still, you might need to spin 100's of instances and that would not be the good approach.

Below are the set of commands you can use :

Spin instance using below Cloudformation template, run it in loop to create multiple instances :

```
---
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: <region>
      ImageId: <amiID>
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName : <KeyName>
```

Use below command to get the intance ID :

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=EC2' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text
```

Using that instance-id, run below command :

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "<instanceID>" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --comment "<COMMENT>" --parameters commands='sudo yum update -y' --output text
```

I don't think docker will be of any help here as that would complicate things for you due to SSM agent installation. So your best bet would be running commands one by one and finally storing your output in S3.